# Where do I put the function necessary to pull and save an uploaded image's file name and how do I refer to it in sqlite (in Flask)?

Tags: python, sqlite, file-upload, flask, wtforms

I have a form (done in Flask) where text and image data are inputted. I'm confused as to where and how I should place the function that extracts the image's file name, then dumps the data into my sqlite database. I've included relevant snippets.
The Main file:

```
@app.route('/dform', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def dform():
    form = DForm()
    return render_template('dform.html', form=form)

@app.route('/adddf', methods=['POST'])
def add_dfentry():    
    g.db.execute('insert into dfentries (name, cover) values (?, ?)',
                (request.form['name'], request.form['cover']))

@app.route('/dfoutput')
def dfoutput():
    cur = g.db.execute('select name, cover from dfentries order by id desc')
    dfentries = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('dfoutput.html', dfentries=dfentries)
```

The Form's file:

```
class DForm(Form):
    name = TextField(u"Name")
    cover = FileField(u"Cover Image")
```

So, how I would get the file name from the above file field, and store it into (and retrieve it from) the database? Thank you for the help and sorry for the possibly stupid question. I am using this program to learn python.

Answer (score 0):

In Flask, the uploads are stored in `request.files`, not `request.form`. You would basically look at `file.filename` and read it into your table as a blob.

See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/ for more information.

Don't forget all security and validation considerations.

And since you're using `WTForms` probably, see http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FileField which teaches you how to actually process it via the Form.

This also pertains to your submit in general, if you're using the form, you shouldn't be accessing the `request` object directly. If you're using `Flask-WTF` use `form.validate_on_submit()`, if you're using vanilla forms use `request.method == 'POST' and form.validate()` instead.

Read up on correct usage at http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/crash_course.html or https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I don't want to save the image as a blob. I just want to save the file name so that I can just do a join for the path name and add it into the output's img src attribute. Do I put the `def` for that in the same file as my form or with my routes? Then how do I reference it in the db?

Comment: The documentation has examples of saving the file and getting the filename. You can store the filename in the database.

Comment: Ok. I got the filename part. But I still don't understand how to save it in the db. I can't see any other way to save form elements other than `request.form/files[]`. `'Request.form['cover']'`, `'request.files['cover']'`, `'cover'`, `'cover'`, `sqlite.Binary('cover')`; none of these have worked. I have read and re-read, but I can't figure it out. I'm totally new to python (and programming), so I might be missing something easy.

Comment: When the file is uploaded, it's going to be uploaded to a temporary location. You have to move the file to a permanent location using `request.files['cover'].save( full_file_path_and_name_of_your_choice )`. Then simply save `full_file_path_and_name_of_your_choice` into the database. Simple as that.

Comment: I put the file path (`os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)`) straight into the db and it finally worked. Is that safe? Thank you so much for your help. Also, how do I upvote/give you points? I'm new to SO.